# How to call function after URLSearchParam?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, stripe-payments

I need redirect page after it load and get param from URL. I can do by button click. But how I can make page redirect automatic after page have get param from URL (without user input)?

Thanks!

```
const handleClick = async (event) => {
  const stripe = await stripePromise;
  const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    param,
  });
}

const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('param');


const Page = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
  return (
    <section >

      <button role="link" onClick={handleClick}>
      Press
    </button>

    </section>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use your useEffect hook there to redirect the page, instead of using the onClick handler. e.g.

```
const handleLoad = async () => {
  const stripe = await stripePromise;
  const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    param,
  });
}

const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('param');


const Page = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleLoad();
  }, []);
  return null;
};

export default Page;
```

Though, you don't really even need to load up React for any of this. You could just make this page a static html page with a script tag that does the redirect logic, or something similar to that.

---

After further discussion, we found out that in order for this stripe stuff to work on Safari-mobile, we needed to wait for the page's load event before calling handleLoad(), so something like this:

```
const handleLoad = async () => {
  const stripe = await stripePromise;
  const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    param,
  });
}

const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('param');
window.addEventListener('load', () => handleLoad())
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But I need wait until `URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('param');` finish (so param != null). How to wait for this?

Comment: URLSearchParams(...).get(...) happens immediately. Is this returning null on you? Are you positive that the current page that's being loaded actually has ?param=value in the URL?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what this page is supposed to do: You visit this page with ?param=value in the URL. This page immediately redirects you to the stripe page using the parameter that was in the URL.

If this is what you're trying to accomplish, then your URLSearchParams() logic is just fine, and you'll have to double check that when you visit the page, you actually have ?param=value in your URL.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes you understand correct. But for some reason on iOS browser it is not redirect automatic. It is require manual button click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218111/discussion-between-scotty-jamison-and-flutterfirebase).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to parse those query parameters in the init/load handler. You can see an example of this [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/checkout-from-email?path=public%2Fclient.js%3A24%3A2). Note that the event listener on `DOMContentLoaded` kicks everything off. An example of this in action can be seen [here](https://checkout-from-email.glitch.me/pay?code=123).

I noticed that your code uses `param` in the Checkout redirect directly. If `param` is a checkout session that you should be generating these on demand, not sending them in emailed links etc, as they are short-lived. In the example above, the `code` param is read and use to generate a new checkout session via a `fetch` and then that is used for the redirect.