# window.addEventListener('load',... not firing on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, safari, gatsby

I need redirect page after it load and get param from URL. I can do by button click.

But I want redirect page automatic (without user input). I am use `window.addEventListener('load', () => handleClick())` and it work well on Chrome. But on Safari (desktop and mobile) it not always fire (only sometimes it fire - not always).

I can see this by add `alert('Beginning');` in handler - on Chrome this fire automatic after page load, but not on Safari.

How I can solve this?

Thanks!

```
const handleClick = async (event) => {

  alert('Beginning'); //For debugging


  const stripe = await stripePromise;
  const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    param,
  });
}

if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('param');
}

const Page = () => {

  if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => handleClick())
  }

  return (
    <section >

      <button role="link" onClick={handleClick}> //Only for fallback
      Press
    </button>

    </section>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event probably wouldn't be very reliable, since your component probably wouldn't be mounted until after the DOM is loaded. Instead, you can use the [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) of React component to respond when your component is mounted to the page. For example:

```js
function Component() {
  useEffect(() => alert(1), []);

  return (
    <h1>hello world!</h1>
  );
}
```

You can find more information about the Effect hook in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Using it with an empty array makes it work *like* [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for class components.

Comment: Thanks for help! But before when I use useEffect() it give me this issue (see comment and discussion): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971266. How you can explain why you solution will still work?

Comment: What is `stripePromise`? I don't have access to Stripe setup, but playing around with some of the examples from the documentation without a real API key [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-cookies-m6kdi?file=/src/App.js) seems to work up until it throws an Error for not being setup fully, including in mobile Safari on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise that you avoid referencing the DOM directly using listeners such as `window.addEventListener` or `document.addEventListener`. In fact, this is why you are using React and not jQuery, to create a virtual DOM instead of charging the real DOM directly and reducing the web performance.

In React, you have [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to achieve what you are trying to do. They expose a bunch of lifecycle methods that trigger some events. In your case, [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) fits your requirements. This hook is similar to `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()`:

> By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do
> something after render. React will remember the function you passed
> (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and call it later after
> performing the DOM updates. In this effect, we set the document title,
> but we could also perform data fetching or call some other imperative
> API.

Due to the needs of Strapi payments and Safari mobile (needs to wait for the page load) I've mixed the hook and your approach to ensure that the effect is triggered when the page is loaded.

Applied to your code:

```
const Page = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => handleClick()) 
  }, []);

  return (
    <section >

      <button role="link" onClick={handleClick}> //Only for fallback
      Press
    </button>

    </section>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Basically, the code will trigger the `useEffect` function once the DOM tree is loaded and it will execute your `handleClick` function. The empty array (`[]`) passed as an argument is called `deps`; means that you are triggering the effect only once. Of course, it will work in all browsers since it's a React feature.

Comment: Thanks for help! But before when I use useEffect() it give me this issue (see comment and discussion): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971266. How you can explain why you solution will still work?

Comment: According to that discussion Safari mobile + Strapi must wait for the page load. In that case, I would suggest mixing both approaches. Using a `useEffect` + `addEventListener`. That would ensure the effect in Safari always works better than your initial approach.

Comment: Thanks! So I can use:

  if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => handleClick())
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleClick();
  }, []);

Comment: Yes of course. If you add it inside a `useEffect` hook it will fire once the DOM is loaded and should do the trick always, not sometimes as it is happening now.

Comment: Thanks! So have both separate should be the best right? window.addEventListener and React.useEffect so if one does not fire the other will fire

Comment: I would recommend putting both together as my code shows. Is quite redundant but it's the workaround for Safari. The hook will trigger what's inside once the DOM tree is loaded so it's a better option to have both together but it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fire a function just in loading page and redirect it to another url you can use auto call function like this

```
(function(){
alert('Beginning');
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('param');
}
if (param !== 'undefined' && param !== null $$ param!==[]){
    window.location.href = 'your_new_url_string?param='+param;
}
})();
```