# How to call function on Safari after page load?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, addeventlistener

I need to redirect the web page after it loads and gets the param from the URL. I can do this with a button click.

However, I want to redirect the page automatically (without user input so better UX). Here I use `window.addEventListener('load', () => handleClick())` and it works well on Chrome, but it does not always fire on Safari (desktop and mobile).

I can debug this by adding `alert('Beginning');` in the handler — on Chrome, this fires automatically after the page load, but not on Safari.

How I can solve this?

```
const handleClick = async (event) => {

  alert('Beginning'); //For debugging


  const stripe = await stripePromise;
  const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    param,
  });
}

if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('param');
}

const Page = () => {

  if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => handleClick())
  }

  return (
    <section >

      <button role="link" onClick={handleClick}> //Only for fallback
      Press
    </button>

    </section>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.addEventListener('load',... not firing on Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752018/window-addeventlistenerload-not-firing-on-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Without clicking the button you can use history.push function.Since it fires as soon as it is called.

```
history.push(location)
```